# how to show popup by clicking on datagridview column in window application using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagrid, datagridview

hi
 I am using datagridview in my window application form. I want that when I click on a particular column of datagridview it popup a window having info containing thatfield. Like I have all data about stds in datagridveiw, but instead of displaying all I want to display only his/her name, rest of information should be appear by clicking on that particular name.

Regards 
      Touseef

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        String info;

        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) // Here specify the column index on click of which you want to display popup
        {
            //your logic here
            info= dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["U_ID"].Value).toString();  // Cells["<specify your cell name for this index>"]
            MessageBox.Show(info);
        }

        else if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) // Here specify the column index on click of which you want to display popup
        {
            //your logic here
            info= dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Name"].Value).toString();  // Cells["<specify your cell name for this index>"]
            MessageBox.Show(info);
        }
    }
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Form1 frm = new Form1(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString())); 
                frm .ShowDialog();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

        }
```

In this code your creating object of another form which u want to show as popup. //`Form1 frm = new Form1.`

And pasing ID value as constructor to those form `Form1` and show as dialogue //`DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value`

Also set Form1 ShowInTaskbar property to `False`

**NOTE:**

You can access that constructor value(ID) from **Form1** and fetch all details by **ID** and display as your wish

Comment: private void DataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
             try
            {
                Viewaddeduser frm = new Viewaddeduser(DataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["FileNo"].Value.ToString()); 
                frm .ShowDialog();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ok" + ex);
            }

        }

Comment: and on viewadded user form  private String FileNo;
        public Viewaddeduser(String FileNo)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
is it correct way?

Comment: an on form load I am making connection with db and making query.. to fetch data on base of fileNo

Comment: exception is that it is unable to find column name FileNo ... what could be the possible reason?

Comment: Try this public Viewaddeduser(String FileNo) { InitializeComponent(); this.FileNos=FileNo }

Comment: If exception is coming, i think column `FileNo' does not exist in your DataGridView